# Devices get address from wrong DHCP pool and bypass router

Tags: dhcp

I have a problem with a network I’m building. I have a modem/router connected via ADSL to the internet.

I’ve setup this router so it has the address `192.168.0.1` with a `/24` mask, and it has its own DHCP server, with a pool that goes from `192.168.0.100` to `192.168.0.200`, and it has a password protected WiFi.

I have a second router connected with the first router via a network cable, this second router has address `192.168.1.1`, a `/24` mask and its own DHCP server with a pool that goes from `192.168.1.100` to `192.168.1.200`.
This second router also has a public WiFi. I’ve set a static route from the first to the second router (to network `192.168.1.0`, `/24` mask and `192.168.0.1` as default gateway).
Likewise, I have a static route from the second router to the first router (to network `192.168.0.0`, `/24` mask and `192.168.1.1` as default gateway).

My idea was to create two different networks with two different set of addresses.

The problem is that devices connected to the second router’s public WiFi get their address form the first router DHCP server (so they are like 192.168.0.xxx).
Moreover if I’m connected to the second router’s public WiFi I can access the first router’s settings panel (which is password protected but still), I guess because since they get the address from the first router’s DHCP (when they shouldn’t) they are in the same subnet, even if they are connected to the second router’s public wifi. I can’t even acces the settings panel of the second router unless I disconnect the network cable connecting the two routers. 
The first router is a  Fritz!Box 3272 and the second router is a TP-Link TD-W8968

Comment: Hi Muffin can you provide a diagram of your network and the IP configurations. it might help us visualise the problem.

Comment: If they are in the same broadcast domain, you will likely have to reserve addresses using hardware mac addresses in dhcp and not have a pool in both dhcp servers.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your connecting the two routers together on their 'Switched' ports as opposed to a routed ported. Most home WIfi routers have 1 router port meant to connect to a modem and 4 switch ports mean to connect to computers, they will put their Wifi on the same subnet as their switched ports. Thus you'll have the 2 Wifis and internal networks in the same broadcast domain with 2 DHCP servers giving out addresses.

To get what you want you'd have to have at least 3 routed ports. One for the internet subnet, one for your protected subnet and one for your public subnet. Sounds like you have 2 routers each with 1 route-able port.

Comment: Both routers have a dedicated ADSL port with an rj11 connector and 4 other port with an rj45. On both router one of the rj45 port is labeled as WAN/LAN1 whereas the other three are just LANx. I’m connecting the using the WAN/LAN port, which I guess is the routed one.

Comment: @Muffin WAN/LAN1 probably means the port can be used as either WAN or LAN port depending on how you configure it.

Comment: Try to verify the wan/lan is configured to be routed, the second router will need an ip on whatever net its connected to on the first router. And the first router will need a static route pointing the public network subnet to the ip of the second router. This seems a bit out of the ability of the typical soho router. U may be able to buy a cheap used cisco router of ebay and a small unmanaged switch to make it work